# The document “Untitled” could not be saved as "Untitled"

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, nsdocument

I am trying to develop a document based mac app using [this Apple walkthrough](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/TextArchitecture/Tasks/TextEditor.html) and I am having issues saving the file (the final step).  The error that I am getting after I try to save a file is: The document "Untitled" could not be saved as "- the new filename is I'm trying to use -"

I've googled around and not found any results for this error.  I've rechecked the code and everything seems pretty solid to the tutorial.  I wondered if anybody has any intuition as to what might be going wrong here.

The code of my main class is:

```
#import "MyDocument.h"

@implementation MyDocument

- (id)init
{
    self = [super init];
    if (self) {
        if (mString == nil) {
            mString = [[NSAttributedString alloc] initWithString:@""];
        }
    }
    return self;
}

- (NSAttributedString *) string { return [[mString retain] autorelease]; }

- (void) setString: (NSAttributedString *) newValue {
    if (mString != newValue) {
        if (mString) [mString release];
        mString = [newValue copy];
    }
}

- (void) textDidChange: (NSNotification *)notification {
    [self setString: [textView textStorage]];
}



- (NSString *)windowNibName
{
    // Override returning the nib file name of the document
    // If you need to use a subclass of NSWindowController or if your document supports multiple NSWindowControllers, you should remove this method and override -makeWindowControllers instead.
    return @"MyDocument";
}

- (void)windowControllerDidLoadNib:(NSWindowController *) aController
{
    [super windowControllerDidLoadNib:aController];

    if ([self string] != nil) {
        [[textView textStorage] setAttributedString: [self string]];
    }
}

- (BOOL)readFromData:(NSData *)data ofType:(NSString *)typeName error:(NSError **)outError
{
    BOOL readSuccess = NO;
    NSAttributedString *fileContents = [[NSAttributedString alloc]
                                        initWithData:data options:NULL documentAttributes:NULL
                                        error:outError];
    if (fileContents) {
        readSuccess = YES;
        [self setString:fileContents];
        [fileContents release];
    }
    return readSuccess;
}

- (NSData *)dataOfType:(NSString *)typeName error:(NSError **)outError
{
    NSData *data;
    [self setString:[textView textStorage]];
    NSMutableDictionary *dict = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObject:NSRTFTextDocumentType
                                                            forKey:NSDocumentTypeDocumentAttribute];
    [textView breakUndoCoalescing];
    data = [[self string] dataFromRange:NSMakeRange(0, [[self string] length])
                     documentAttributes:dict error:outError];
    return data;
}
```

Header file:

```
#import <Cocoa/Cocoa.h>

@interface MyDocument : NSDocument
{
    IBOutlet NSTextView *textView;
    NSAttributedString *mString;
}

- (NSAttributedString *)string;
- (void) setString: (NSAttributedString *)value;

@end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I rebuilt the project from scratch with one exception: I didn't follow the step of dragging my MyDocument class to the File's Owner.  The tutorial was written for a previous version of XCode even though it says it's for 3.2 (or maybe that much has happened in that version and now), but that step is unnecessary.

Answer (score 0):

In your `-dataOfType:error:` method, when you assign something to `data`, are you sure it's not nil? Returning nil will cause this error.

Comment: Yep.  From gdb: `print (unsigned int) [data length]` returns `$1 = 271`